# How to make sense of the 'Downloading blocks' status and numbers?

Tags: mist

I want to build mist from source. I started  the mist application for the very first time following the instruction here: https://github.com/ethereum/mist#run-mist. I did not have any wallet so I did not import any. This is the splash screen I see:

[image]

I don't know how to make sense of the numbers as seen in the lower right hand corner.

Why does it mean by `Chain structure 99.50%)`? It does not correspond to 1,844,506 divided by 4,6430,330.

Additionally, if I want to run my wallet locally, the splash screen seems to suggest I have to download the all the blockchain history. Is it correct?

Comment: What do you mean running locally?

Comment: I am trying to build from the source. See https://github.com/ethereum/mist#run-mist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 1844506 out of 46430330 does not correspond to that percentage. The bigger number is the number of blocks mined on the Ethereum blockchain all together till current time. see here: https://etherscan.io/blocks.

The progress of the blocks downloading is shown in the small line at the bottom as shown below [image: Mist blocks sync]

If you want to launch the mist while it is still syncing, close the mist and restart it and then click **Launch Application.** 
Thanks. Hope this answer helps 
For more details regarding How to use mist refer here:
https://medium.com/@attores/step-by-step-guide-getting-started-with-ethereum-mist-wallet-772a3cc99af4

Comment: If I restart `mist`, will the download start again from very beginning? Where are the downloaded block stored on my local machine?( I am running macos)

Answer (score 1):

yes blocks will get downloaded from where it left.
The downloaded block details can be found by navigating to **File** --> **Backup** --> **Accounts** see below:[image: Account Backup]

And a folder pops up with **geth** and **keystore** sub folders. The keystore folder contains your account's **private key** file and the **geth** folder contains the downloaded block details in the **chaindata** folder. you can check progress of downloaded blocks by seeing the size of the **chaindata** folder. see below:[image: Chaindata folder]